# Linking "helpful flags" to available close-votes for 20k+

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

For people who are active in the SO community, it is quite common to run out of close votes. It is especially noticeable, when chat rooms like try to do some controlled cleanup in their particular areas.

The 50 close votes is just too low (and same actually goes for delvotes too).

The best way IMHO, would be for high-rep users to gain additional close votes based on helpful flags. This would mean that you have to already participate on managing the site, before you are entrusted with additional responsibilities. And would ensure that the additional ability to close bad question is not simple gained based on users urge for rep-whoring.

**One vote per 100/200 flags**, would seem a sensible rate (there is 50 flag cap per day). Preferably the effect should be applied starting from 500 flags (to counteract people who were just collecting for a badge).

Comment: Given that reputation anf helpful flag count is a measure of community trust, I think it's sensible to enable people to do community chores. It's a reasonable request. +1 from me.

Comment: Definitely agree with his idea

Comment: The goal here is to bypass the "reputation problem" and instead benefit people who already are willing to invest time in "garbage duty" - flagging bad answers and questions.

Comment: Given the number of questions waiting for close votes is always very high (50K iirc) this seems very sensible. This is a solution for an actual need. I don't think that 20K+ reputation is a good way to measure it, I think that the amount of previous helpful votes, and the ratio between helpful and unhelpful votes might be a more important factor.

Comment: Maybe even allow any user over 3k-5k-10k that has the [CV-Steward] and [Marshal] badges to get an extra vote for every ten flags over 500. It's a voluntary act that gives no additional benefit after all.

Comment: IMHO 10k rep would be enough with that flag count +1